# Assign a unique url to click a specific button on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page is an FAQ page with horizontal tabs running along the top. These tabs list categories, coded as below:

```
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'cntab3')">category1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'cntab4')">category2</a></li>
```

Within each tab, I have buttons that when clicked, will load a div element. I'd like to make it so that each button has a unique URL, for example, if I type in the URL www.example.com/tab1-faq3, on page load, tab1 will be clicked, and FAQ3 will be clicked to load that content.

I tried searching and messing around java, but I can't seem to find the best solution. Could anyone point me in the right direction on achieving this?

Appreciate it!

Comment: I would assume all you have to do is ensure your server understand the request for the custom Url and when rendering your page it could pass expected states through means of data attributes or similar which then can trigger JavaScript to read the state object when the page is loaded to force the state upon the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL parameter (in my example, via shebang), and then trigger a click on a specific DIV (be it the one on the shebang, or one selected according to the shebang). In the example, going to div.htm#tab will change the div color to red.

```
<div class="tab">Hey!</div>
<script>
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
    $(".tab").click(function() {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    })
    $("."+hash).trigger("click"); // or $("."+hash).click()
</script>
```

You need to check that the action on the URL is the one you actually want, so as to avoid someone from triggering other div's click events.

Comment: Manually triggering an event can be dangerous.

Comment: @ErikPhilips never heard of that. How? And how do I mitigate the risks?

Comment: In larger environments, you may not know what events other developers and attached to an element and code you did not expect or want to execute can execute (not necessarily malicious).

Comment: Oh, I see. This was just a small example though I can see how it can end up like that if used incorrectly. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `onclick` it's legacy, it creates very hard code to debug and is not best practices if you're using jQuery.  Please take a moment and read [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

> Within each tab, I have buttons that when clicked, will load a div element.

With html:

```
<li>
  <a class="tablinks js-content" 
     data-content="cntab3" 
     data-target=".cntab3-content">category1</a> 
</li>
<li>
  <a class="tablinks js-content" 
     data-content="cntab4" 
     data-target=".cntab4-content">category2</a>
</li>

//... more html

<div class="cntab3-content"></div>
<div class="cntab4-content"></div>
```

Using jQuery you can bind your click event like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('js-content').on('click', function(){
    loadContent($this);
  });

  function loadContent($element){   
    var content = $element.data('content');
    var $target = $($element.data('target'));

    var url = // something with content.
    $.get(/*whatever with url*/)
      .done(function (html) {
        // however you want to append html
        $target.html(html);
      });
  }

  if (window.location.href // check location, if match) {
    var $element = $('[data-content="' + hrefvalue + '"]');
    if ($element.length == 1) {
      loadContent($element);
    }
  };
});
```